# Spring Boot Application throws Out of Memory Exception when multiple requests are sent

Tags: spring-boot, rest, garbage-collection, out-of-memory

I have a Spring Boot application with multiple REST endpoints. I'm attempting to send around 50 requests to a basic health check endpoint. However, this is causing an OutOfMemoryError. I tried increasing the Xmx value, but it's not a reliable solution. It works for 100 requests, but then the same error occurs again. How can I prevent this issue?

Found the cause: in my case server.max-http-header-size was set too high. Using the default value resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

One of your REST endpoints has a memory leak. Increasing the amount of memory is never the best option.
You should make a heapdump on OutOfMemory and check if something is wrong somewhere. They are many resources on the Internet on how to achieve that.

To generate and analyze Heap Dump : https://reflectoring.io/create-analyze-heapdump/

Comment: I have analyzed the heap dump, which reveals that 99.1% of the memory is occupied by `byte[]` objects referenced by Tomcat classes. Even after the request is completed, the heap memory does not decrease.

Comment: Are you storing the requests you receive somewhere ? Without your code we can't help you. If you want to narrow which endpoint is causing the issue try each one if them separately until you find the faulty one. Then you can share your code